# Can´t install composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I get this message installing composer: "unable to execute file in temporary folder" Setup Aborted. Access denied.

I tried to install it by console, but the command line doesn´t recognize php like intern o extern command.

Comment: This site is for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [executable](https://getcomposer.org/download/) file and run it